# How to append the output of a function in a normal mapping command

Tags: vim, ag

I have this mapping in vim

> map f :Ag --ignore node_modules

I would like to append the result of the 'getcwd()' at the end of the command.

Something like (not working, but gives the idea):

> map f :Ag --ignore node_modules :call getcwd()

So the command in vim would look like

> :Ag --ignore node_modules ~/project

**More context**

I am using The silver search through vim using ag.vim. I want to have a normal mode mapping that specify the current working directory in the ag command.

https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher

https://github.com/rking/ag.vim

Thank you.
JF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
nnoremap <expr> f ':Ag blahblah '. getcwd()
```

if you don't provide the directory, `ag` will take current directory, the same as `getcwd()` right?

Comment: Hi, command does not work. I keep getting 'E78: Unknown mark'. For your comment about the directory, the documentations says "{directory} (which defaults to the current directory)". Since I change often of cwd using NERDTree, I would like to see the directory I am currently in to minimize the human errors facto while I work. :)
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you added  expr in your mapping?

Comment: I gave it another try ot morning and it worked! I must havedone a mistake before. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Vim's evaluation rules are different than most programming languages. You need to use `:execute` in order to evaluate a variable; otherwise, it's taken literally; i.e. Vim uses the variable name itself as the argument.

```
nnoremap f :execute 'Ag blahblah ' . getcwd()<CR>
```

This is an alternative to @Kent's use of `<expr>`.

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way is to use the expression register via `<c-r>=` to execute the expression, `getcwd()`

```
nnoremap <leader>f :Ag blahblah <c-r>=getcwd()<cr><c-b><s-right><s-right>><space>''<left>
```

I added the parts after the `<cr>` to insert single quotes after `blahblah` and put the cursor in between them.

Note: Don't overshadow the `f` command. It is very handy. See `:h f`. Look into use leader. See `:h mapleader`

For more help see:

```
:h c_ctrl-r
:h "=
:h c_ctrl-b
:h c_<s-right>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are using an interesting approach with the expression register. I did not know about that. Thanks for sharing. Also, I reassure you, my mappings looks like that: 

nnoremap <expr> <leader>f ':Ag --ignore node_modules --ignore assets -S "" "' . getcwd() . '"<C-Left><Left><Left>'

and 

nnoremap <expr> <leader>fw ':Ag --ignore node_modules --ignore assets -S "<C-r><C-w>" "' . getcwd() . '"<C-Left><Left><Left>'

 
I did not display the full mapping in the original post for simplicity. I am basically doing the same thing as you. :)